# C# LINQ left join 2 Datatables

Tags: c#, linq, join, datatable

I have 2 Datatables, they should join on "UserID" but it doesn't work. I've read the docs and other solutions but they wont work either.

```
var dtjoined = from DataFileInfos in FileInfo.AsEnumerable()
                       join Recips in dtMail.AsEnumerable()
                       on DataFileInfos["UserID"] equals Recips["User name"]
                       into Tb3
                       from Tb3row in Tb3.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select Tb3;
```

I want at the end a datatable with a left join. I don't get the gist of LINQ, even reading the docs, can someone explain me that?

And how do I get the datatable?
I would do something like

```
foreach(var enum in dtjoined)
{
//do something to add that
myDatatable.rows.add(enum);
}
```

---

EDIT:
FileInfo:

```
Datatable FileInfo = new Datatable();
FileInfo.Columns.Add("Anything",typeof(anything));
...
FileInfo.Columns.Add("UserID",typeof(string));
```

dtMail:

```
Datatable dtMail= new Datatable();
    dtMail.Columns.Add("Anything",typeof(anything));
    ...
    dtMail.Columns.Add("User name",typeof(string));
```

These were my two tables and I want them to join on `UserID`
So at the end I got the following result:

```
[FileInfo Column1] [FileInfo Column2] [FileInfo Column3] [FileInfo UserID] [dtMail E-Mail]
SomeValue            SomeValue             SomeValue          UserID1          SomeMail
```

Comment: "...doesn't work..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: Nope I just cant enumerate the results. I want a datatable at the end

Comment: have you tried to use the debugger and inspect  `dtjoined` - does it implement `IEnumerable`?

Comment: What you mean you _"just cant enumerate"_ the results?

Comment: `FileInfo` and `dtMail` is a list or what? try to complete the details here maybe somebody can help you asap.

Comment: Which columns would you want in resulting `datatable` from linq query?

Comment: I want to join 2 Datatable as I said on the title, sorry. I should mention it in the description as well.

Because LINQ cant join 2 Datatables, but their enumerates. I wanted to join them on UserID.

FileInfo Left join dtMail, so I get the results from FileInfo as well as the addendum of dtMail with UserID as key

Comment: I still don't fully understand what is your problem. If you want result in `DataTable`, take a look at **[DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable?view=netframework-4.7.2)**.

Comment: @V.Hunon, I means which columns do you want from linq query to datatable?

Comment: @er-sho, I want all records from FileInfo and the Email-Recipients of dtMail, there key is UserID

Comment: @V.Hunon FileInfo and dtMail are what type ?. To perform join using linq both should be in IQueryable list type.

Comment: FileInfo and dtMail are of type Datatable ofc. Because I want to join 2 Datatables...

Comment: please share more code which explains every things regardinging FileInfo and dtMail objects.

Comment: Edited. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

try this below code and in below i just used some class just to show you how we can return a custom object using LinQ.

```
var dtjoined = from DataFileInfos in FileInfo.AsEnumerable()
                   join Recips in dtMail.AsEnumerable()
                   on DataFileInfos.Field<string>("UserID") equals Recips.Field<string>("User name") 
                   select new { FirstColumn= DataFileInfos.FirstColumn, ... }; // or select new { FirstColumn= DataFileInfos.FirstColumn, ... }.ToList();
```

this will return an object and incase you want a list than select DataFileInfos or Recips object or you can also go for creating another object which holds a list.